# C++ : How to assign the same input to a string and an integer in 2 lines?

Tags: c++

I'm a very beginner in C++ and I'm actually following [the Google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/edu/c++/getting-started#learn-by-example).

Trying to go a little further with the second example, here is my problematic : **checking if the input is a number and, if not, being able to restate it in the error message**.

Here is a way I used to solve that but the code length tells me that there is a shorter way :

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

bool IsInteger(string str) {
  size_t non_num_position = str.find_first_not_of("0123456789-");
  size_t sign_position = str.find_first_of("-", 1);

  if (non_num_position == string::npos && sign_position == string::npos) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

void Guess() {
  int input_number = 0;
  string input_string;

  do {
    cout << "Try to guess the number between 0 and 100 (type -1 to quit) : ";

    cin >> input_string;

    if (!IsInteger(input_string)) {
      int input_string_length = input_string.size();

      cout << "Sorry but « " << input_string << " » is not a number." << endl;

      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(input_string_length, '\n');
      continue;
    }

    input_number = atoi(input_string.c_str());

    if (input_number != -1) {
      cout << "You chose " << input_number << endl;
    }
  } while (input_number != -1);

  cout << "The End." << endl;
}

int main() {
  Guess();
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the shorter way I try to follow but `cin` seems to be "emptied" once assigned to `input_number` (because of the bitwise operator ?) :

```
void Guess() {
  int input_number = 0;
  string input_string;

  do {
    cout << "Try to guess the number between 0 and 100 (type -1 to quit) : ";

    if (!(cin >> input_number)) {
      getline(cin, input_string);

      cout << "Sorry but " << input_string << " is not a number." << endl;

      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(100, '\n');
      continue;
    }

    if (input_number != -1) {
      cout << "You chose " << input_number << endl;
    }
  } while (input_number != -1);

  cout << "The End." << endl;
}
```

---

**SOLUTION :**

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Guess() {
  int input_number = 0;
  string input_string;

  do {
    cout << "Try to guess the number between 0 and 100 (type -1 to quit) : ";
    cin >> input_string;

    try {
      input_number = stoi(input_string);

      if (input_number != -1) {
        cout << "You chose " << input_number << endl;
      }
    }
    catch (const exception&) {
      cout << "Sorry but " << input_string << " is not a number." << endl;
    }
  } while (input_number != -1);

  cout << "The End." << endl;
}

int main() {
  Guess();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your first attempt is that IsInteger is unnecessarily complicated and long.  Otherwise, you had the right idea.  Your second attempt is much less correct.... once you read from cin, the data is gone.  So, as in the first attempt, you need to store the data in a string.

Here's an example which is a little shorter and doesn't need IsInteger at all:

```
size_t p = 0;
int input_number = std::stoi(input_string, &p);
if (p < input_string.length())
{
    cout << "Sorry but " << input_string << " is not a number." << endl;
    conitnue;
}
```

`stoi`'s second argument tells you where the conversion to integer stopped working.  So if there was non-int data in the string (such as '123abc') then p will be somewhere before the end of the string.  If p is at the end, then the whole string must have been a number.

Comment: Thank you @SoapBox :)

I had to struggle a little because it throws an exception that I couldn't see via editor + term compilation, silently failing on `std::stoi(input_string, &p)`, which causing the program to terminate. I added a try/catch as in the solution above.